# need to calculate total time month wise in django

Tags: python, django

I have created function to calculate total time.

```
def emp_attendance(request):
    attendance_list_ad = Attendance.objects.all()
    total = None
    for item in attendance_list_ad:
        if item.total_time is not None:
            if total is None:
                total = item.total_time
            else:
                total += item.total_time
    return render(request, 'employee/emp_attendance.html'{'attendance_list_ad': attendance_list_ad, 'total': 
                               total})
```

while print:

attendance date =
2023-01-09
total_time =
1: 00: 00

so my question is in front page this function is calculating total time of all enteries which are in data base . But i want to calculate total time month wise as in attendance date we have month 01 . then total time will be calculated

Comment: please share model code. what is data type for total_time field?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get sum of total time for each month you can do it like this...

```
attendance_list_ad = Attendance.objects.filter(Date_field__year='2022').values_list('month').annotate(total_time=Sum('total_time'))
```

But if you are using dateTime field, and not just the month for each item. You could try doing the following, though I doubt it will work.

```
attendance_list_ad = Attendance.objects.filter(Date_field__year='2022').values_list('Date_field__month').annotate(total_time=Sum('total_time'))
```